# creating lags for zoo objects

Tags: r, loops, time-series, lag, zoo

I have been creating lags for zoo objects using the following `econ$gdp4 <- lag(econ$gdp, k = -4, na.pad = TRUE)`.  I have about 6 columns in `econ` object that I want to create lags for and I want to create lags for periods 1 through 9.  Is there a way to use a loop to create these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose z is our zoo object.  Lets say we want 9 lags for each of columns 2, 3, 4 as well as all columns of the original. Then try:

```
merge(z, lag(z[, 2:4], -(1:9)))
```

Also note that a lag of 0 gives back the same column so this gives the original as well as 9 lags of each column:

```
lag(z, -(0:9))
```

Comment: I've run into a problem when I try to plot one of the lags: plot(econ$abi.lag-6).  I get an "error in plot.window" message.  I assume this is because the "-6" is being interpreted as an operation.  Is there a way around this?  Thanks

Comment: `econ$"abi.lag-6"` (backticks work too) or `econ[, "abi.lag-6"]` .